# Помощь с MySQL-запросом

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Есть таблица сообщений (ticket_id - id переписки) между менеджерами и пользователем.

[image]

Если manager_id не NULL, значит это сообщение менеджера, иначе юзера (его id хранится в переписке, потому что переписка ведется с одним юзером и несколькими менеджерами).
Как только, ответил менеджер, мне нужно получить первое сообщение после предыдущего ответа менеджера. То есть юзер может написать 5 сообщений подряд, но мне надо первое.
На картинке приведен пример: последняя строка - сообщение менеджера, выделенная - нужное мне сообщение юзера.
Нужно как бы циклом спускаться пока manager_id is not null, но как это одним запросом вытащить не могу придумать.
То ли группировать как-то хитро такие последовательные сообщения

Comment: Если бы вопрос относительно SQL задавал я, то показал бы не таблицу, а ту часть схемы БД, которая имеет отношение к запросу. И, может быть уважаемые дали бы совет не по поводу технологии, а относительно архитектуры. Мне кажется, что Ваши трудности можно обойти изменениями архитектуры. Прежде всего, смущают меня NULL-поля во вторичном ключе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здравствуйте!

Эмитировала Вашу таблицу в MySQL, убрав неважные для поиска поля:

```
id   manager_id  datetime_create 
43   1           21.03.2014 13:36:48
92   null        21.03.2014 13:37:04
93   1           21.03.2014 13:37:18
128  null        21.03.2014 13:37:27   <-- требуется
129  null        21.03.2014 13:37:36
130  1           21.03.2014 13:37:46   <-- известно
```

Я так понимаю, на момент необходимости поиска Вам известен `id` записи ответа менеджера. Получился такой скрипт для приведенного примера.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  test.tm
WHERE
  id > (SELECT id
        FROM
          test.tm
        WHERE
          id < 130
          AND manager_id IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY
          id DESC
        LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1
```

В результате выдает следующую строку.

```
128  null        21.03.2014 13:37:27
```

Разберу по действиям.

Смотря на данные и по своему опыту исходила из того, что `id` является счетчиком и по нему можно отследить порядок получения сообщений.

Подзапрос **(1)** возвращает `id` предыдущего ответа менеджера.

```
SELECT id
FROM
  test.tm
WHERE
  id < 130                      -- id требуемой записи меньше известного (*)
  AND manager_id IS NOT NULL    -- manager_id у записи пустое
ORDER BY id DESC                -- сортировка в обратном порядке
LIMIT 1                         -- и ограничение в 1 запись выдают последний ответ
```

Далее внешний, основной запрос выдает следующую за последним ответом менеджера запись.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  test.tm
WHERE
  id > ( подзапрос )            -- id требуемой записи больше найденного
ORDER BY id                     -- сортировка в прямом порядке
LIMIT 1                         -- и ограничение в 1 запись
```

---

Если необходимо пропустить предыдущие, подряд идущие ответы менеджера, то в подзапросе на место `id` известной записи в строке **(*)** можно подставить следующее:

```
SELECT id
FROM
  test.tm
WHERE
  id < 131
  AND manager_id IS NULL
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Подзапрос **(2)** ищет последнюю запись пользователя перед ответами менеджера. Тогда уже "предыдущий" ответ будет искаться относительно его `id`. В запросе правда тогда возникает трехэтажность.

Если вернуться к примеру таблицы, добавить пару строк (127 и 131) для наглядности работы запроса и искать сообщение пользователя для записи 131, то получится следующий порядок действий:

```
id   manager_id  datetime_create 
43   1           21.03.2014 13:36:48
92   null        21.03.2014 13:37:04
93   1           21.03.2014 13:37:18   <-- 2: найдет подзапрос (1)
127  null        21.03.2014 13:37:20   <-- 3: результат запроса
128  null        21.03.2014 13:37:27   
129  null        21.03.2014 13:37:36   <-- 1: найдет подзапрос (2)
130  1           21.03.2014 13:37:46
131  1           21.03.2014 16:31:45   <-- известно
```

Правленый вариант:

```
SELECT *
FROM test.tm
WHERE id > (SELECT id
            FROM test.tm
            WHERE id < (SELECT id
                        FROM test.tm
                        WHERE id < 95
                              AND manager_id IS NULL
                        ORDER BY id DESC
                        LIMIT 1)
              AND manager_id IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY id DESC
            LIMIT 1)
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: если будет два сообщения менеджера подряд, будет пустая выборка.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov , да, точно, этот вариант событий не учла.
Если искать необходимо сообщение пользователя непосредственно перед ответом, то можно так поправить.

SELECT *
FROM
  test.tm
WHERE
  id < 131               -- id записи пользователя меньше известного
  AND
  id > ( подзапрос )
  AND manager_id IS NULL -- искать записи пользователя
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1

Если предыдущее сообщение от менеджера - ответ придет пустой. А так чтобы пропустить предыдущие ответы и искать перед ними с наскоку не приходит в голову. Надо подумать.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov , добавила в ответ решение с учетом пропуска предыдущих, подряд идущих ответов менеджера: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2c258/1

Comment: @Ata297, да. осталось учесть случай, что предыдущих ответов менеджеров не было. Т.е. тикет открыт юзером, соответственно начальный этот комментарий получить не удастся.

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот как-то так. Для каждого ответа менеджера выбирается первый комментарий пользователя:

```
select min(prevuserfirst.id) as prevuserfirstid, currentmanagerandprevmanager.managerid
from
  ( select max(prevmanager.id) as prevmanagerid, currentmanagerandprevuser.managerid
    from 
     (  select max(prevusers.id) as prevuserid, manager.id as managerid
        from tm prevusers
        join tm manager on prevusers.id<manager.id
        where
          prevusers.manager_id is null
          and manager.manager_id is not null
        group by manager.id) currentmanagerandprevuser 
      left join tm prevmanager on 
               prevmanager.id < currentmanagerandprevuser.prevuserid
               and prevmanager.manager_id is not null
    group by currentmanagerandprevuser.managerid) currentmanagerandprevmanager
  left join tm prevuserfirst on 
               prevuserfirst.id > currentmanagerandprevmanager.prevmanagerid
               or currentmanagerandprevmanager.prevmanagerid is null
group by currentmanagerandprevmanager.managerid
```

Идем изнутри. Т.е. самый внутренний подзапрос вернет для каждого ответа менеджера первый ответ юзера (он не обязательно будет первым).
Далее определяем предыдущий ответ менеджера - он будет максимальным (по id) ответом менеджера, относительно полученного ответа юзера.
Далее уже получаем первый ответ юзера, следующий непосредственно после полученного ответа менеджера.

Для поиска для конкретного ответа менеджера условие

```
and manager.manager_id is not null
```

заменить на

```
and manager.id = 123
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06576/17

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с одним подзапросом и одной группировкой:

```
   SELECT t.* 
     FROM  (SELECT mg.ticket_id,
                   mg.id, 
                   MIN(ct.id)       AS ii,
                   mg.manager_id    AS mng, 
                   ct.manager_id    AS cst
              FROM tickets_messages AS mg
              JOIN tickets_messages AS ct
                ON mg.id < ct.id 
               AND mg.ticket_id = ct.ticket_id
          GROUP BY mg.id
            HAVING mng IS NOT NULL
               AND cst IS NULL
          ORDER BY id DESC
             LIMIT 1) AS h
LEFT JOIN tickets_messages AS t
       ON h.ii = t.id;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ebf7/1/0)

Comment: та же тема. если не было предыдущих ответов менеджера (первыми были комментарии пользователя), будет пусто.